# Setting a return value in debugger in C in order to find input arguments

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb

Is there a way in C (using a debugger) to set the return value and find out what arguments would return that value?
For example, if I have a function that takes in three integers, does something inside the function, and returns an integer, is there a way for me to set the return value as 0, and find out which integers when inputted give that return value?

I tried using an online GDB debugger, as well as the gdbgui debugger (from Linux). I understand how the debugger works and have been setting breakpoints but was wondering if there is an easy way to do this.

Wording of question:
"Using a source-level debugger, determine for what values of arguments
the function returns a zero."

Comment: There really is no way this could be possible for the debugger.

Comment: Imagine that such a feature would be offered by any tool. Now you feed the return value which is the encrypted version of an input. Even if the other input, the encryption key, would be known, that feature would mean to decrypt without the decryption key (at least in case of asymmetric algos). There are less extreme cases in which what you are asking for would still be hard. While it is probably not possible to answer convincingly "No." I assume that there will be no "Yes.".

Comment: I think you'll need to write your own unit test to figure this out.

Comment: Maybe you can restrict the scope of your question to invertable functions. Otherwise please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem , which might provide you with a different approach to ask your question and get the help you need in case that my pessimism holds up and you do not get a different answer. I would consider that adding needed focus to your question.

Comment: I was told to use a debugger for this which is why I asked. The assignment is to use a debugger to find input arguments that output 0. The purpose is to learn how to use a debugger. However, I also do not think it is possible using a debugger after playing around with it. That's why I asked, hoping others may have more insight.

Comment: You can call functions from within the debugger. Is your assignment to brute force determine which arguments output 0 or is there some formula you’re not showing us?

Comment: Assignment is to brute force

Comment: Can you add the exact wording of your assignment to your question?

Comment: Using a source-level debugger, determine for what values of arguments
the function returns a zero.

Comment: hmm I dunno.. debugger not the right tool for this IMO. If it's a black box function, I'd write a test function that feeds every possible value into it and see what returns 0 (if this is even computationally feasible). Maybe gdb has some built-in functionality to do this? I don't know. Reading the source, maybe even the assembly, would be other options.

Comment: Set a conditional breakpoint on return value and print function arguments after breakpoint is hit.

Comment: Is there an upper limit? There are infinite possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this operation is about learning the `gdb` debugger ...

1. Set a breakpoint on the `return` statement of the function. In the example below, this is line 13, so we want `b 13`.
2. Only execute the breakpoint if the return value is 0. We want: `cond 1 ret == 0`
3. Print the argument values at the breakpoint. We use `commands 1` to set `gdb` commands to be executed at the breakpoint. We want `p a1`, `p a2`, and `p a3` to print the arguments. And, then, we want `c` to continue execution after the breakpoint.

---

Here is a simple sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef LIM
#define LIM     5
#endif

int
func(int a1,int a2,int a3)
{

    int ret = a1 + a2 + a3;

    return ret;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int a1 = -LIM;  a1 <= LIM;  ++a1) {
        for (int a2 = -LIM;  a2 <= LIM;  ++a2) {
            for (int a3 = -LIM;  a3 <= LIM;  ++a3)
                sum += func(a1,a2,a3);
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n",sum);
}
```

---

We build the above program with (e.g.):

```
cc -g -o program program.c
```

In the above program, the `return` for `func` is line 13.

Here are the `gdb` commands we'd use. In this example, we put them in a file (e.g. `cmds`), but they could just as easily be entered at the command prompt:

```
b 13
cond 1 ret == 0
commands 1
echo "a1 is "
p a1
echo "a2 is "
p a2
echo "a3 is "
p a3
c
end
run
quit
```

We invoke `gdb` with the command:

```
gdb -q -x cmds ./program > out
```

---

Here is the output (e.g. `out`):

```
Reading symbols from ./program...done.
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401143: file program.c, line 13.

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-5, a2=0, a3=5) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$1 = -5
"a2 is "$2 = 0
"a3 is "$3 = 5

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-5, a2=1, a3=4) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$4 = -5
"a2 is "$5 = 1
"a3 is "$6 = 4

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-5, a2=2, a3=3) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$7 = -5
"a2 is "$8 = 2
"a3 is "$9 = 3

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-5, a2=3, a3=2) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$10 = -5
"a2 is "$11 = 3
"a3 is "$12 = 2

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-5, a2=4, a3=1) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$13 = -5
"a2 is "$14 = 4
"a3 is "$15 = 1

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-5, a2=5, a3=0) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$16 = -5
"a2 is "$17 = 5
"a3 is "$18 = 0

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-4, a2=-1, a3=5) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$19 = -4
"a2 is "$20 = -1
"a3 is "$21 = 5

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-4, a2=0, a3=4) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$22 = -4
"a2 is "$23 = 0
"a3 is "$24 = 4

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-4, a2=1, a3=3) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$25 = -4
"a2 is "$26 = 1
"a3 is "$27 = 3

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-4, a2=2, a3=2) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$28 = -4
"a2 is "$29 = 2
"a3 is "$30 = 2

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-4, a2=3, a3=1) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$31 = -4
"a2 is "$32 = 3
"a3 is "$33 = 1

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-4, a2=4, a3=0) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$34 = -4
"a2 is "$35 = 4
"a3 is "$36 = 0

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-4, a2=5, a3=-1) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$37 = -4
"a2 is "$38 = 5
"a3 is "$39 = -1

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-3, a2=-2, a3=5) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$40 = -3
"a2 is "$41 = -2
"a3 is "$42 = 5

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-3, a2=-1, a3=4) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$43 = -3
"a2 is "$44 = -1
"a3 is "$45 = 4

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-3, a2=0, a3=3) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$46 = -3
"a2 is "$47 = 0
"a3 is "$48 = 3

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-3, a2=1, a3=2) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$49 = -3
"a2 is "$50 = 1
"a3 is "$51 = 2

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-3, a2=2, a3=1) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$52 = -3
"a2 is "$53 = 2
"a3 is "$54 = 1

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-3, a2=3, a3=0) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$55 = -3
"a2 is "$56 = 3
"a3 is "$57 = 0

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-3, a2=4, a3=-1) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$58 = -3
"a2 is "$59 = 4
"a3 is "$60 = -1

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-3, a2=5, a3=-2) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$61 = -3
"a2 is "$62 = 5
"a3 is "$63 = -2

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-2, a2=-3, a3=5) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$64 = -2
"a2 is "$65 = -3
"a3 is "$66 = 5

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-2, a2=-2, a3=4) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$67 = -2
"a2 is "$68 = -2
"a3 is "$69 = 4

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-2, a2=-1, a3=3) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$70 = -2
"a2 is "$71 = -1
"a3 is "$72 = 3

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-2, a2=0, a3=2) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$73 = -2
"a2 is "$74 = 0
"a3 is "$75 = 2

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-2, a2=1, a3=1) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$76 = -2
"a2 is "$77 = 1
"a3 is "$78 = 1

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-2, a2=2, a3=0) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$79 = -2
"a2 is "$80 = 2
"a3 is "$81 = 0

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-2, a2=3, a3=-1) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$82 = -2
"a2 is "$83 = 3
"a3 is "$84 = -1

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-2, a2=4, a3=-2) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$85 = -2
"a2 is "$86 = 4
"a3 is "$87 = -2

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-2, a2=5, a3=-3) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$88 = -2
"a2 is "$89 = 5
"a3 is "$90 = -3

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-1, a2=-4, a3=5) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$91 = -1
"a2 is "$92 = -4
"a3 is "$93 = 5

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-1, a2=-3, a3=4) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$94 = -1
"a2 is "$95 = -3
"a3 is "$96 = 4

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-1, a2=-2, a3=3) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$97 = -1
"a2 is "$98 = -2
"a3 is "$99 = 3

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-1, a2=-1, a3=2) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$100 = -1
"a2 is "$101 = -1
"a3 is "$102 = 2

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-1, a2=0, a3=1) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$103 = -1
"a2 is "$104 = 0
"a3 is "$105 = 1

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-1, a2=1, a3=0) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$106 = -1
"a2 is "$107 = 1
"a3 is "$108 = 0

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-1, a2=2, a3=-1) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$109 = -1
"a2 is "$110 = 2
"a3 is "$111 = -1

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-1, a2=3, a3=-2) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$112 = -1
"a2 is "$113 = 3
"a3 is "$114 = -2

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-1, a2=4, a3=-3) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$115 = -1
"a2 is "$116 = 4
"a3 is "$117 = -3

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=-1, a2=5, a3=-4) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$118 = -1
"a2 is "$119 = 5
"a3 is "$120 = -4

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=0, a2=-5, a3=5) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$121 = 0
"a2 is "$122 = -5
"a3 is "$123 = 5

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=0, a2=-4, a3=4) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$124 = 0
"a2 is "$125 = -4
"a3 is "$126 = 4

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=0, a2=-3, a3=3) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$127 = 0
"a2 is "$128 = -3
"a3 is "$129 = 3

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=0, a2=-2, a3=2) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$130 = 0
"a2 is "$131 = -2
"a3 is "$132 = 2

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=0, a2=-1, a3=1) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$133 = 0
"a2 is "$134 = -1
"a3 is "$135 = 1

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=0, a2=0, a3=0) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$136 = 0
"a2 is "$137 = 0
"a3 is "$138 = 0

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=0, a2=1, a3=-1) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$139 = 0
"a2 is "$140 = 1
"a3 is "$141 = -1

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=0, a2=2, a3=-2) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$142 = 0
"a2 is "$143 = 2
"a3 is "$144 = -2

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=0, a2=3, a3=-3) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$145 = 0
"a2 is "$146 = 3
"a3 is "$147 = -3

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=0, a2=4, a3=-4) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$148 = 0
"a2 is "$149 = 4
"a3 is "$150 = -4

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=0, a2=5, a3=-5) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$151 = 0
"a2 is "$152 = 5
"a3 is "$153 = -5

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=1, a2=-5, a3=4) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$154 = 1
"a2 is "$155 = -5
"a3 is "$156 = 4

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=1, a2=-4, a3=3) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$157 = 1
"a2 is "$158 = -4
"a3 is "$159 = 3

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=1, a2=-3, a3=2) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$160 = 1
"a2 is "$161 = -3
"a3 is "$162 = 2

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=1, a2=-2, a3=1) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$163 = 1
"a2 is "$164 = -2
"a3 is "$165 = 1

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=1, a2=-1, a3=0) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$166 = 1
"a2 is "$167 = -1
"a3 is "$168 = 0

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=1, a2=0, a3=-1) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$169 = 1
"a2 is "$170 = 0
"a3 is "$171 = -1

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=1, a2=1, a3=-2) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$172 = 1
"a2 is "$173 = 1
"a3 is "$174 = -2

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=1, a2=2, a3=-3) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$175 = 1
"a2 is "$176 = 2
"a3 is "$177 = -3

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=1, a2=3, a3=-4) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$178 = 1
"a2 is "$179 = 3
"a3 is "$180 = -4

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=1, a2=4, a3=-5) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$181 = 1
"a2 is "$182 = 4
"a3 is "$183 = -5

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=2, a2=-5, a3=3) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$184 = 2
"a2 is "$185 = -5
"a3 is "$186 = 3

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=2, a2=-4, a3=2) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$187 = 2
"a2 is "$188 = -4
"a3 is "$189 = 2

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=2, a2=-3, a3=1) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$190 = 2
"a2 is "$191 = -3
"a3 is "$192 = 1

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=2, a2=-2, a3=0) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$193 = 2
"a2 is "$194 = -2
"a3 is "$195 = 0

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=2, a2=-1, a3=-1) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$196 = 2
"a2 is "$197 = -1
"a3 is "$198 = -1

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=2, a2=0, a3=-2) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$199 = 2
"a2 is "$200 = 0
"a3 is "$201 = -2

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=2, a2=1, a3=-3) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$202 = 2
"a2 is "$203 = 1
"a3 is "$204 = -3

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=2, a2=2, a3=-4) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$205 = 2
"a2 is "$206 = 2
"a3 is "$207 = -4

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=2, a2=3, a3=-5) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$208 = 2
"a2 is "$209 = 3
"a3 is "$210 = -5

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=3, a2=-5, a3=2) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$211 = 3
"a2 is "$212 = -5
"a3 is "$213 = 2

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=3, a2=-4, a3=1) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$214 = 3
"a2 is "$215 = -4
"a3 is "$216 = 1

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=3, a2=-3, a3=0) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$217 = 3
"a2 is "$218 = -3
"a3 is "$219 = 0

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=3, a2=-2, a3=-1) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$220 = 3
"a2 is "$221 = -2
"a3 is "$222 = -1

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=3, a2=-1, a3=-2) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$223 = 3
"a2 is "$224 = -1
"a3 is "$225 = -2

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=3, a2=0, a3=-3) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$226 = 3
"a2 is "$227 = 0
"a3 is "$228 = -3

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=3, a2=1, a3=-4) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$229 = 3
"a2 is "$230 = 1
"a3 is "$231 = -4

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=3, a2=2, a3=-5) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$232 = 3
"a2 is "$233 = 2
"a3 is "$234 = -5

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=4, a2=-5, a3=1) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$235 = 4
"a2 is "$236 = -5
"a3 is "$237 = 1

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=4, a2=-4, a3=0) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$238 = 4
"a2 is "$239 = -4
"a3 is "$240 = 0

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=4, a2=-3, a3=-1) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$241 = 4
"a2 is "$242 = -3
"a3 is "$243 = -1

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=4, a2=-2, a3=-2) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$244 = 4
"a2 is "$245 = -2
"a3 is "$246 = -2

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=4, a2=-1, a3=-3) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$247 = 4
"a2 is "$248 = -1
"a3 is "$249 = -3

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=4, a2=0, a3=-4) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$250 = 4
"a2 is "$251 = 0
"a3 is "$252 = -4

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=4, a2=1, a3=-5) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$253 = 4
"a2 is "$254 = 1
"a3 is "$255 = -5

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=5, a2=-5, a3=0) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$256 = 5
"a2 is "$257 = -5
"a3 is "$258 = 0

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=5, a2=-4, a3=-1) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$259 = 5
"a2 is "$260 = -4
"a3 is "$261 = -1

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=5, a2=-3, a3=-2) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$262 = 5
"a2 is "$263 = -3
"a3 is "$264 = -2

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=5, a2=-2, a3=-3) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$265 = 5
"a2 is "$266 = -2
"a3 is "$267 = -3

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=5, a2=-1, a3=-4) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$268 = 5
"a2 is "$269 = -1
"a3 is "$270 = -4

Breakpoint 1, func (a1=5, a2=0, a3=-5) at program.c:13
13      return ret;
"a1 is "$271 = 5
"a2 is "$272 = 0
"a3 is "$273 = -5
0
[Inferior 1 (process 1816035) exited normally]
```

Answer (score 2):

The assignment doesn't mean you should figure out which magic command inverts a function and paste it to the debugger window. There is no such command<sup>1</sup>.

The assignment as I understand it means you should investigate what the function does, understand its logic, and derive the inverse function, using the debugger as a tool that helps you observe behaviour of the code.

---

<sup>1</sup> That can be used in practice, at any rate. There is a finite number of machine integers. You could write a script that tries every possible input, but you may or may not live long enough to see it finished running.